# Best way to wait for a method to finish?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, wait

I am working on something and I need a method to finish before I am calling another one. The thing is, I am having a hard time figuring out how should I do this. I have searched for blocks and async tasks, but I didn't reach a conclusion and I want to ask you guys for suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code please. It's hard to help without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Basically just fetching some data in the first place, and after that doing something with it.

Comment: So, what was it you found about block and async tasks that wasn't any good? Also, you didn't mention anything about fetching stuff from a network in your question. Perhaps that would be quite important.

Comment: There is a framework called AFNetworking that will help you.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific about it, but I was referring to fetching the data from a local storage, so AFNetworking won't help much. I was just asking for a tutorial or a guideline on how to use blocks or async stuff or something that would manage to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it:

- `UINotification`, the async task will post this notification and the main thread will subscribe this notification.
- delegation pattern, if that async task is created on separate class, you can create protocol on that class. And implements that protocol on your main class. You can take a look at multiple delegate classes on iOS, like `UITableViewDelegate`, `UIScrollViewDelegate`. The summary is, The Async task running on separate class will call its delegate when certain event finish, like task is completed.
- use block variables, you can create your method signature for async task, something like:

  `- (void)asyncTask:(void(^)())completionHandler;`

and in your main method, you can call:

```
[self asyncTask:^{
    [self asyncTask2:^{
    }];
}];
```

Normally, I will use block variables if async tasks are on the same class or it is just one time thing. If there are quite lot of tasks, I will create separate class and use delegate. Notification is always my last resort because it is harder to debug and it is more tightly coupled in my opinion.

Comment: We use completion handlers widely throughout our apps, sometimes to perform delegate methods. The combination of the two allow a more extensive decoupling between conceptual layers within the app. An additional approach is dispatching both tasks on a serial queue.

Comment: Yes, agreed on the combination of both method. Oh, and I forget to mention GCD